# How can I create a backup of my computer like amazon's AMI

Tags: windows-7, backup, disk-image, windows-7-backup

Hello I use a windows 7 desktop, and in the last 4 weeks I have had 12 developers join my team, and it has been a hard time to get their boxes up and running. I was researching an option where I could create an image of the latest stable dev environment and the new developers can use it right away, very similar to how amazon's AMI works.

Is there a way or a program that I could use to build an image??

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx), you can use it to build, capture and deploy images. I don't know how close it is to Amazon's platform, but in terms of being able to get systems up and running, its second to none. If you're using a properly configured MDT setup, it can rebuild systems in less than 30 min, and users never lose files and settings if the user state migration tool is used.

First install MDT 2012 Update 1. Then install the ADT for windows 8. (it's backwards compatable with Win7, so don't worry)